# Microsoft Graph Calendar API OData filter on start / end date-times

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve only certain events from a user's `calendarView` in the Microsoft Graph Calendar API.

I've written the following proof-of-concept code:

```py
start = self.date_to_string(datetime.datetime.now())
end = self.date_to_string(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 365 * 3))
start, end = min(start, end), max(start, end)

data = await self.make_request(url, parameters = {
  "startDateTime" : start,
  "endDateTime" : end,
  "$filter" : "Start/DateTime ge '2017-07-01T08:00'" # and (start/dateTime ge '2020-10-21T16:31:40.5470240')"
})
```

Though, when I make the request, this is what I'm getting

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
    "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-10-22T15:20:56",
      "request-id": "bef9513d-a5b3-4b23-b37a-8f341f6822ae",
      "client-request-id": "bef9513d-a5b3-4b23-b37a-8f341f6822ae"
    }
  }
}
```

Removing the `$filter` helps, but I do need it (I would like to filter events starting in a date-time range and/or ending in a date-time range).

I tried several things:

- `cast(2017-07-01T08:00 as Edm.DateTimeOffset)`
- `2017-07-01T08:00Z`
- `2017-07-01T08:00Z+00:00`

Actually pretty much any combination one can think of, but to no avail. Note that [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) use different formats, including `'2017-07-01T08:00'` (as in `?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2017-07-01T08:00'`)

Any ideas?

Comment: I am looking into it. Will get back to you..

Comment: Really nice of you, thanks :)

Comment: Please use the properties on event resource-type for filtering:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0.
CalendarView provides the list of expanded events in the specified time range.

Comment: This doesn't really help me @Diana: the properties I'm trying to filter on, which are `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` are listed in the `event` resource type, so I should be able to filter on them. CalendarView gives me the events in the specified time range but I'd like to provide more complex constraints than what it allows me to do...

Comment: I'm looking at the event resource type reference and can't find these properties: `startDateTime` or `endDateTime` - perhaps you can use `start` and `end` instead?